# Where does Mail.app store the email addresses/aliases for your own accounts?

Tags: mail.app, email, accounts, defaults

I'm trying to programatically access the email addresses configured in Mail.app. I looked through `defaults read com.apple.mail` but they don't appear there. I also had a look in `sqlite3 ~/Library/AccountsAccounts4.sqlite`, but similarly had no luck.

I'd LOVE to be able to change/append to them programatically, but it would also be useful to just be able to READ what's there.

Answer (score 3):

AppleScript has objects for managing mail accounts.  They provide a programatic way of reading and creating accounts. Once you get it working it will be more robust than reading and writing using `defaults` or `sqlite3`.

I don't have first hand experience but a web search gave me these links:

- [Displaying mail account information with AppleScript](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/applescript/mail_accts/)
- [Creating an account and sending mail using applescript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156412/creating-an-account-and-sending-mail-using-applescript)

Here is the dictionary entry for the `account` object:

[image: Mail account in AppleScript]

The examples in the links should give you a start into developing your own solutions in AppleScript.

Comment: This is great. I am able to successfully use this to manipulate the email addresses of aliases:

`set email addresses of account "Home" to {"user@host.com", "user2@host.com"}`

But AppleScript does not appear to be able to set the names of each alias.

Comment: @jaydisc You are now well ahead of me in scripting Mail! Glad you are making some progress.